# Accessing SharePoint through Java Application

Tags: sharepoint, document

HI

I want to access my sharepoint site through my java application or through jsp pages. At my website user can search and download documents from sharepoint document library.if any java api? plz send me sample code..

Regards
Siva

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library

Library written in Java provided connectivity to Microsoft SharePoint 2007 and 2010 Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can using this <strike>http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/camelot-wcf-service/</strike>

- http://camelottoolkit.codeplex.com/
- http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/camelot-sharepoint-integration-toolkit/

Alongside with the Camelot ADO.NET Connector it turns SharePoint to an ordinary SQL datalayer so you can select, insert, update and delete from your Lists and Document Libraries (full CRUD support).

I'm not really into java, but there are sample code of using the WCF service and PHP is available here, http://blog.bendsoft.com/2011/04/camelot-php-tools-1-1-for-sharepoint-released/

There are a few soap wsdl clients for java, but it should be a simple task of setting it up.

Comment: The link doesn't wokrk

Answer (score 0):

You can check out WSRP then you may be able to show your web parts in java portlets.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Remote_Portlets
I remeber testing it in SharePoint 2007 to show lists in a java portlets.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an API to access most common Sharepoint Rest API functions (i'm still in work in progress to achieve a full implementation). The idea is to have a very easy to use java API to work with sharepoint sites. You can take a look here

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java